# Aplicação não abre no windows XP por que não tem permissão de administrador

Tags: c#, permissões, windows-xp

Estou tendo um problema, o executável do meu programa não roda no windows XP por conta de problemas de permissão de usuário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nos demais sistemas, você coloca ele para rodar como administrador e ele funciona normalmente.

Pesquisando na internet achei várias sugestões como essa:
[C#: Forçar uma aplicação a executar como administrador](http://www.codigomaster.com.br/desenvolvimento/ccharp-forcar-uma-aplicacao-a-executar-como-administrador)

O que não deu resultado, apesar de incluir o manifest como orientado.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então achei esse tutorial da microsoft que parece resolver o meu problema:
[Step 6: Create and Embed an Application Manifest (UAC)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx)

Mas devido a minha dificuldade em entender o inglês não consegui reproduzir ele corretamente.

Alguém pode me ajudar com respeito a isso?

Comment: Qual versão do VS esta a utilizar?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015

Comment: @PedroMapelli Eu não tenho acesso ao site que indicou - o que não deu resultado. Portanto, não sei se é a mesma coisa que publiquei como resposta. Neste caso, o que fiz (na resposta), resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Esse link eu tentei e não deu certo, o problema é que estou executando o programa no Windows XP, e nele não aparece essa janela que você postou para executar com administrador. Em resumo, esse é o problema.

Comment: Mas você adicionou o `manifest` em sua aplicação?

Comment: Inseri da forma como esta na imagem que adicionei na pergunta.

Comment: No XP não existe UAC, então ou você está usando uma conta com permissão de administrador ou uma conta com acesso limitado, não tem como forçar a rodar como administrador, no máximo você detecta que não é administrador e avisa pro usuário que não pode rodar

Comment: Pois é, no caso mesmo estando em uma conta de administrador a aplicação não abre dando erro informando que esta sem permissão. Então queria forçar a aplicação a rodar com permissões de administrador.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve adicionar um `manifest` em sua aplicação.

**Menu Project > Add New Item...** e depois escolha o tipo **Application Manifest File**:
[image: add new item]

Após isto, você deverá determinar o nível de permissão de `"asInvoker"` para `"requireAdministrator"`.

Ao criar o arquivo, ele vem com a linha assim:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

Troque para ficar deste jeito:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Ao executar seu programa, será solicitado permissão de administrador (caso seja usuário comum).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]